# How to use dictionary from other funtion to another

Tags: python, function, dictionary

Im a beginner and please help, what exactly i need to use to next one:
i want to use dictionary data with name & color from init_dict to show_dict and print it all

```
from printing_functions_1 import init_dict as pr
from printing_functions_1 import show_dict as sd

pr('DArya', 'Total Black', another_color = 'purple', lovely_film = 'mystic')
sd(another_color = 'purple', lovely_film = 'mystic')

def init_dict(name, color, **argv):
    argv['Name'] = name
    argv['Color'] = color


def show_dict(**argv):
    for key, value in argv.items():
        print(key, value)
```

expect somethinglike this from output with `show_dict`:

```
another_color purple
lovely_film mystic
Name DArya
Color Total Black
```

Comment: Are you exploring how unpacking with `**argv` might work or is that part of your attempt to solve the issue?